# Assign values conditionally in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I need to create a new variable and assign values to the row based on another categorical variable. [The data table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVkQ7.png)

Specifically, I want to create a variable called channel_num. If the strings in channelGrouping equal to "Direct", "Display" and "Paid Search", I will assign 0 to this row; if they equal to "Organic Search" and "Social", I will assign 1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your datatable is named `df`:

```
df$channel_num <- ifelse(df$channelGrouping %in% c("Direct","Display","Paid Search"), 0, ifelse(df$channelGrouping %in% c("Organic Search","Social"), 1, NA))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me questions